# Session Timeout Doesn't Hit the Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpsession

I have enabled the session timeout in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
       ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
 }
```

setting it to 1 min for testing. Now I have created an action filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;


        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and registered it in `FilterConfig.cs` by adding `filters.Add(new SessionExpireFilterAttribute());`. I have also placed the attribute `[SessionExpireFilter]` on the `customercontroller` class.

Now what happens is that if I click a button that sends a request to an action `customer/edit` while the session has expired, the the code does hit a breakpoint in the `customercontroller` `constructor` and then a 200 is returned. It never hits the breakpoint in the actionfilter. It also never hit the actual action `edit` either.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are debuging in a wrong place. Does it hit breakpoints in any other places?

Comment: Not really. It goes there and and then disposes some of the dbcontext/EF objects.

Comment: I mean: try to set breakpoint somewhere else and check if you can hit it. For example, set breakpoint at `app.UseCookieAuthentication(...)`.

Comment: Yes. `app.UseCookieAuthentication(...)` is hit on application launch. Then all the controlers/actions and filter action is hit correctly before the session expires. If I hit the button while session is valid, then the breakpoint in the action filter is hit. But if I leave it for a minute or so, and hit the button, it only goes to the controller's constructor and a 200 is returned.

Comment: Then it looks like a caching. Does your response contains `Cache-Control` HTTP header?

Comment: Yes, I see `Cache-Control: private` in the header. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't remember how to do it exactly, but I'm sure if you google for "asp.net disable caching" or "asp.net set cache expiration" you will found an answer.

Comment: @vasily.sib thank you for guiding me to the right direction. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Cache-Control` from  HTTP header.

Prevent caching in MVC, we created our own attribute, you could do the same. Here's our code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then just decorate your controller with [NoCache]. OR to do it for all you could just put the attribute on the class of the base class that you inherit your controllers from (if you have one) like we have here:

```
[NoCache]
public class ControllerBase : Controller, IControllerBase
```

You can also decorate some of the actions with this attribute if you need them to be non-cacheable, instead of decorating the whole controller.

Or you can use the built in cache attribute to prevent caching.

For .net Framework: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`

For .net Core: `[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. That helped alot.